# VS shows class name in curly brackets after value (VB.NET)

Tags: json, vb.net

This probably a really really simple thing but I just cant figure it out.

So I'm trying to make a general function in my project that could parse whatever JSON I throw at it into an easy to use object in vb.net. I tried `JSON.NET` but it seemed to me that you need to create a class for every different JSON structure so I decided to use `JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize` from the `System.Web.Scripts.Serialization` library.
All seems to be good and it looks to me that this function is capable of parsing any JSON without the need to create an class for it beforehand but when I tried to extract values from it, I ran into a bit of trouble.
So usually when I make a string and then print it in the Immediate window, it just prints the string. But if I print an element of my parsed JSON, it prints the class name after it.

Here is my code:

```
Dim jss = New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim out = jss.Deserialize(Of Object)(jsonString)
Dim a = "test"
Dim b = out("name")
```

My JSON string looks like this:
    `{"name": "test", "data": "Hello"}`

Now when I print object a it gives:

```
?a
"test"
```

But if I print object b, I get:

```
?b
"test" {String}
    String: "test"
```

The same thing happens with integers and other data types

Why is this happening and how could I get my value from the JSON object without the other stuff that was printed after it?

Also, if anyone knows a quick way to parse JSON into something readable in VB.net (without creating different classes for all JSON structures I plan to use) then feel free to let me know :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was generally worried about the {String} part after my string whe nI print it in Immediate window.
However if you have any tips on how to easily parse JSON then I'm all ears :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing that you already have your `json object`, you can use `Newtonsoft` as your `json parser`. First, you have to download [Newtonsoft](https://json.codeplex.com/) then add reference in your visual studio. Then import these codes:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
```

And you can have this code to parse your `json object`

```
For Each value As Object In yourJsonObject
    token = JObject.Parse(value.ToString())
    Dim name = token.SelectToken("name")
    Dim data = token.SelectToken("data")         
Next value
```

remember, as the loop keeps going, the value of `name` and `data` overrides; therefore, at the end of the loop you get the last value of `name` and `data` in your `json object`. To print all values, make sure to add the `console.writeline()` code inside the loop. Like this:

```
For Each value As Object In yourJsonObject
    token = JObject.Parse(value.ToString())
    Dim name = token.SelectToken("name")
    Dim data = token.SelectToken("data")       
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Data: {1}", name.toString, data.toString)  
Next value
```

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful.
My json object is just a string. I guess thats fine right?

Comment: this code is applicable for json OBJECT. Try to re-construct it, maybe it could be of use for json string. haven't tried it yet but everything's possible in our field. I posted that answer 'cause you were asking for this>>> "how could I get my value from the JSON object"

Comment: Thanks. I tried parsing a JSON string with it and it seems to work.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry that I forgot. Done now

Answer (score 0):

The other stuff is because you have an object reference to the string, instead of a string reference - if you were to `Console.WriteLine(...)` or `Debug.WriteLine(...)` those, you'd not get the type information

Comment: Thanks.
Is this ok? Should I try to remove the reference somehow or is it ok if it just stays there? It looks a bit messy to me :/

Comment: You're looking at it in a debug tool that is trying to be helpful and show you more information about what it is. When you actually use it in your application, none of that will show, unless you go to the effort of making it show.